# Does a Google maps API Key expire after a certain time?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I've looked around a bit and can't seem to find an answer. I just inherited a halfway done android app project and the Maps don't seem to work.

I see there is an API Key in the xml file, but is there a way to know if it is still valid ?

Thanks.

Comment: you need a same debug.keystore file who generated the api key at first time or you need to generate new api key with your debug.keystore file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The maps API key is tied to the certificate that you're using to sign the APK. This will be different for each Android SDK installation. If another developer has been working on this previously, you'll need to generate a new key based upon your SDK Debug Certificate http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html#getdebugfingerprint then generate a new API key http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html#registering

Comment: I obtained a new key and it work. It seems the key was in fact expired.

Answer (score 3):

The API key is connected to the signing key. It doesn't have an expiration date but the signing key does. If you use the debug key signing key it will expire after one year.  The  Signing Release key must expire no earlier than Oct 22, 2033. (I use 100 years) Don't know how to check the validity period of a certificate, but it's relatively easy to get a new Google Maps API key.  See my [Google Maps guide](http://www.myskylla.com/articles/Google_Maps.html9)

Answer (score 1):

Not really (other than attempting to call the service). You can register your own key by following the steps outlined here: [How Do I Get My Signing Key](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/webservices/index.html#GettingKeys)

Answer (score 1):

What is the age of your project ?
I've been reading somewhere that API keys can't expire, but maybe the author has requested to remove it or requested a new one.